# How to find out why a UITextField ended editing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextField` that can be set into editing mode.

Normally, editing is ended by entering „Done“ on the keyboard.
This calls `textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)`, where some housekeeping happens.

In rare cases, however, an alert is shown that the user entered a geofence. If the text field is then in editing mode, it resigns first responder status since the alert view becomes first responder, and `textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` is also called. When the alert is dismissed, the first responder status of the text field is restored.

**The problem:**
I have to distinguish both cases:
If the text field ends editing because of a Done on the keyboard, housekeeping should happen.
If it ends editing because an alert was shown, housekeeping must not be done.

So, how can I distinguish both cases?

I tried to use the delegate function

```
textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason)
```

where `reason` may be `cancelled` or `committed`, both in both cases the reason is `committed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `textFieldShouldEndEditing` and assuming you can identify that the geofence has been triggered, return false, which will leave the textField in edit mode, otherwise return true, and the housekeeping can begin

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    // assuming you take the same action for all TextFields
    // assume geoFenceHasBeenTriggered is a class-variable true / false
    return !geoFenceHasBeenTriggered
}
```